# I am getting an error while trying to download binary for mysql 5.5.11

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, installation, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade MySQL 5.1 to 5.5.11 on Ubuntu 10.10. Everytime I try the `wget` command I get this error:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.11-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz/from/http://mysql.llarian.net/
--2012-01-27 16:16:08--  http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.11-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz/from/http://mysql.llarian.net/
Resolving dev.mysql.com... 156.151.63.11
Connecting to dev.mysql.com|156.151.63.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not found
2012-01-27 16:16:08 ERROR 404: Not found.
```

Comment: I think you have to be logged into mysql.com to download binaries so wget might fail. Have you tried using you OS's package manager? Something like an `apt-get *name_of_app*` ... ?

Comment: apt-get gives me an error `E: Invalid operation http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.11-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz/from/http://mysql.llarian.net/`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you got that link from http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/?  At any rate, MySQL is up to 5.5.20 now and I don't think they offer older versions of 5.5.x.  If you want an older GA release, you'd have to download 5.1.61.

If you visit http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ in your browser, you can get a correct URL to a current version.